# Can an Android malware install a SSL/TLS certificate into non-root devices?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, android

Does there exist some standard API that allow an Android malware to download and install a SSL/TLS certificate as RCA, in the default keystore, in non-root devices?

I think that this is a very underestimated problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any app can create a new `KeyStore` and do arbitrary things with it. So it is possible for a malware to import a downloaded root CA and use it for TLS connections *originating from the malware itself*.

This does, however, not impact any other app, as global `KeyStore`s are not affected. To change it using official APIs, one needs to create an install intent via [`createInstallIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html#createInstallIntent%28%29), which can then be used to bring the certificate installation dialog up. Unless the user confirms the dialog, the certificate will not be installed.

---

Note that this answer does not consider exploits or other means outside of regular APIs to gain write access to global `KeyStore`s, as your question explicitly asks for standard API only. An app with root access can of course use other means to change the list of root CAs.

Comment: Do you know if a standard API to list or simply count all the installed root or user certificates in the global keystore exists?

Comment: @VanDir For root CAs: I'm not sure if intermediate CA's are returned by [`X509TrustManager. getAcceptedIssuers()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html#getAcceptedIssuers%28%29) as well, but that might be a starting point. From a short search, [this overview article about `KeyChain`s in general](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/03/unifying-key-store-access-in-ics.html) describes the overall API ideas, so it might be helpful as well.